# How do I make AJAX calls to a JSON file in my Github repository

Tags: ajax, github

I have written this simple javascript code to perform a get request on my github repository

```
var url='https://github.com/mypath/AjaxPractice/myFile.json';
myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  XHR.open('GET', url, true)
  XHR.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  XHR.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200)  {
            console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
    }
    XHR.send();
});
```

However I get this error message:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://github.com...(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If a correct request is not allowed because of CORS , you have no options other than use something something like CORS-ANYWHERE here: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to do it:

1. Go to your github repo and click on settings
2. Scroll down to where it says source and change it from none to master branch.

Note: the example I used didnt require XHR.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');